# Log4j is corrupting logs when used in concurrency

Tags: java, multithreading, logging, concurrency, log4j

I have a use case where i have to perform UI tests in concurrency mode (upto 500 users). For doing this, i am using Selenium in headless mode and log4j for logging. I read log4j is thread safe. However, when running with 20 users itself i saw corruption in my log file. I didn't want to create different log files for each thread as it won't make sense to open each file to analyze issues. Hence, i am writing it to a single file.

I am creating an instance of logger and using it to log messages.

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(xyz.class);
logger.info("");
```

Corrupted log file.

> 2018-09-13 14:26:50  INFO [thread 10] (SearchAndAddDataAsset.java:149)
>   - Thread 35 :Check if project 'project55' e2018-02018-09-13 14:26:50  INFO [thread 17] (SearchAndAddDataAsset.java:65) - Thread 42
>   :Screenshot captured

log4j configuration file

> log4j.rootLogger=INFO, FILE
>   log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
>   log4j.appender.FILE.ImmediateFlush=true
>   log4j.appender.FILE.Append=false
>   log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
>   log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}
>   %5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

I am setting log file name inside the script based on class name.

Could someone please suggest the work around here ?

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: INFO [thread 17] (SearchAndAddDataAsset.java:65) - Thread 42 :Screenshot captured. Is mismatching thread number reason for believing that logs are corrupted ?

Comment: No @Vishal. If you look at the logs, those are 2 different log messages written/overwritten on a same line.